# Using specific features of some backends in ErrBot

Tags: errbot

I'm using the telegram backend for ErrBot. 
I know that telegram API allows for messages to use markdown and html. If I understand everything well, I could change:

```
self.telegram.sendMessage(msg.to.id, body)
```

for something using *parse_mode* indicating, for example, *Markdown* but I was wondering if there are any plans to change this (maybe adding a parameter in the configuration or in the communication functions for the bot). Or, maybe, there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find it in the documentation, but it is available: [19. Backend-specifics](http://errbot.io/en/latest/user_guide/plugin_development/backend_specifics.html)